# How to have the columns appear in the row section in a Power BI table or matrix or any other visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix visual with row as Customer. The values are Sales and forecast.

Thus, each row shows me the customer, and the columns are sales and forecast.

Is there a way to make the columns appears as rows, thus the row should show:

```
Customer1 sales salesvalue
Customer1 forecast forecastvalue
Customer2 sales salesvalue
Customer2 forecast forecastvalue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nearest way to achieve this is "Switching values to rows" option in the matrix visual properties under Values > Options.